# Redirection between two websites within one solution (ASP.NET + VS 2008 + IIS 5.1)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis, redirect

I have an issue with redirecting from one asp website to another within one VS solution.
I have set up virtual directories as follows:
C:\WebSites\Website1 - /Website1 
C:\WebSites\Website2 - /Website2
My starting website is Website1. I want to redirect user to Website2. I use Response.Redirect("/Website2/Default.aspx") and get 404 error.
What am I doing wrong? 
Any advices are highly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say the current page is

```
   http://localhost/Website1/Default.aspx,
```

if you do a Redirect like this

```
   Response.Redirect("/Website2/Default.aspx")
```

in there, the URL you are redirecting is

```
    http://localhost/Website1/WebSite2/Default.aspx
```

which don't exists.

You have to redirect to a full URL instead of a relative URL.

Something like
     Response.Redirect("http://localhost/Website2/Default.aspx")

Hope it Helps

Comment: Thank you for your post. I tried to use http://127.0.0.1/Survey/Default.aspx and it works but this is not something I want to have hard coded. Is there any possibility to use virtual path?

Comment: I would add a key to the appSetting of the config file with the URL of the server of the other application and configure it under deployment. Something like <appSettings> <add key="otherServerURL" value="http: //localhost/" /> </appSettings> and do Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["otherServerURL"] + "Website2/Default.aspx"); Maybe someone here can give us another answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could always pick the server name out of the [HttpRequest.Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx) or [HttpRequest.ServerVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx) objects.

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://{0}/WebSite2/default.aspx", 
                                Request.Url.Host));
```

Or

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://{0}/WebSite2/default.aspx", 
                                Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]));
```

Which will save you hardcoding the server name in the redirects.

Answer (score 0):

When you have two virtual directories, if they are configured to be their own applications, then their individual roots are considered THE root, and you will have to redirect to a full URL.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can I reconfigure apps anyhow differently so to be able to use virtual path?

Comment: Well, you could try Response.Redirect("~/../Website2/Default.aspx"), but I have no idea if ti will work.