# Avoid using full path from a different project in solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have built a new WebApi project.
When I debug it I can access a service like this:

```
http://localhost:54864/api/values/5
```

Now I added a new website to the solution.
Do I need to access is with the full path,

```
 http://localhost:54864/api/values/5
```

Or is there a way I could just use api/values/5?

Comment: you don't need to write all the uri, just use `~/api/values/5` in the first case.

Comment: ~/ doesn't work for me from another website, in the same solution.

Comment: They look like the same website to me. Have you tried something like  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786980/redirection-between-two-websites-within-one-solution-asp-net-vs-2008-iis-5)?